# How to match and print list of comma separated numbers in python?

Tags: python, regex

There are several questions regarding this topic, but none of them seem to answer this question specifically.

If I have the pattern `p='([0-9]+)(,([0-9]+))*'` and `s='1,2,3,4,5'` and I run `m = re.match(p, s, 0)` I get a match (as expected).  However, I would like to be able to print the list `('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')`.  I can't seem to do this with the `re.match` output.  It gives me `('1', ',5', '5')`.

Also, how do I get the number of matches (in this case 5)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use regexes for that. `s.split(',')` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Bingo. Astute observers will also notice that that pattern will not match negative numbers.

Comment: This will not validate if the string is in correct format.

Comment: No, but it's much easier to validate each of the fragments in turn (using e.g. `s.isdigit()` with a bit of special casing for negative numbers). Still no need for regexes.